# BitBlt function produces empty bitmap when compiled for x86 in .NET 2.0 VB app

Tags: vb.net, x86, bitblt

I have a BitBlt wrapper function in my VB project.  It works just fine when compiled as Any CPU, but when I aim it at x86 it creates an empty bitmap.  I must use x86 as other parts of the app require it.  Any ideas what could be wrong?  Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

''' <summary>
''' Provides the static method ControlCapture used to
''' take screenshots of the specified control.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>This fails unless compiled targeting Any CPU!!!</remarks>
Public Class ControlCapture

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Pointer to gdi.exe win32 function.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hDestDC">destination device context</param>
    ''' <param name="x">x coord. of output rectangle</param>
    ''' <param name="y">y coord. of output rectangle</param>
    ''' <param name="nWidth">width of source and dest. rectangle</param>
    ''' <param name="nHeight">height of source and dest. rectangle</param>
    ''' <param name="hSrcDC">source device context</param>
    ''' <param name="xSrc">x coord. of rectangle to capture</param>
    ''' <param name="ySrc">y coord. of rectangle to capture</param>
    ''' <param name="dwRop">mode (raster op)</param>
    ''' <returns>0 on failure, non-zero on success</returns>
    ''' <remarks>from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147810 </remarks>
    Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestDC As Long, _
         ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, _
         ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long, _
         ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Grab a screen capture of the given control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control">control to grab</param>
    ''' <returns>Bitmap image</returns>
    ''' <remarks>used by mappoint map viewer and bing map viewer</remarks>
    Public Shared Function ControlCapture(ByVal control As Control) As Bitmap

        'capture params
        Dim width As Integer = control.Width
        Dim height As Integer = control.Height

        'output object
        Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        'get handles to source and destination objects as graphics
        Dim sourceGraphics As Graphics = control.CreateGraphics()
        Dim destGrahpics As Graphics = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)

        'actual handles
        Dim sourceGraphicsPointer As System.IntPtr = sourceGraphics.GetHdc()
        Dim destGraphicsPointer As System.IntPtr = destGrahpics.GetHdc()

        'get references as ints
        Dim destAddress As Integer = destGraphicsPointer
        Dim sourceAddress As Integer = sourceGraphicsPointer

        'call win32 api
        BitBlt(destAddress, 0, 0, width, height, sourceAddress, 0, 0, Codes.SourceCopy)

        'clean up
        sourceGraphics.ReleaseHdc(sourceGraphicsPointer)
        destGrahpics.ReleaseHdc(destGraphicsPointer)

        Return bitmap
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' SRCCOPY(CC0020)      Copies the source bitmap to destination bitmap.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147810 </remarks>
    Private Enum Codes
        SourceCopy = &HCC0020
    End Enum

End Class
```

Thanks,
brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty classic problem with VB.NET, the pinvoke declaration is wrong.  The one you use only works for VB6, a language that for historical reasons uses Integer for a 16-bit number, Long for a 32-bit number.  This goes back to early versions of VB that ran on 16-bit operating systems.  VB.NET was redesigned to work well on 32-bit operating systems, its Integer is 32 bits, its Long is 64 bits.  You have to declare the arguments as Integer.  It works in 64-bit mode by accident.

Use [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) to get the proper declaration.

And take a good look at Graphics.CopyFromScreen and Control.DrawToBitmap for very similar functionality without needing pinvoke.

Comment: From here on out my standard operating procedure is going to be 1) go to stack overflow and ask someone who knows what they're doing, and 2) try to figure it myself.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Also i cant use DrawToBitmap because it's an activex control that i'm trying to grab.  Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Graphics.CopyFromScreen uses BitBlt().